# Провели для студентов (?)урок мужества(?)

Tags: кавычки

Нужны ли кавычки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, к этому наименованию обязательно применение заглавной буквы (скорее всего, в первом слове). Без этого кавычки не подходят по стилю: это может придать оттенок иронизирования (нечто в кавычках, как говорят в устной речи). Добавлять ли кавычки (для обозначения границ названия)? Если заглавная буква только в первом слове, то они опять-таки испортят впечатление. Встречаются и менее стандартные варианты без кавычек (заглавная буква в обоих словах - нетипично для названий без устоявшейся аббревиатуры, либо только во втором слове). Вероятно, с учётом нестандартности самого вида урока, допустимы все три упомянутых варианта без кавычек; из них более формален вариант с первой заглавной буквой.

Answer (score 3):

Словосочетание **Урок мужества** (так же, как словосочетание **Вахта памяти**)  требует прописной буквы в первом слове. Прописная буква показывает единичность, значимость события, мероприятия (ср.урок алгебры), а также даёт ему название. Выражения такого типа *урок (чего?) алгебры* по понятным причинам чрезвычайно распространены, привычны, кавычки в них мы не ставим. В Вашем примере также достаточно прописной буквы.

Но сочетание "урок мужества" иногда употребляется в другом, переносном значении: *Они увидят, как большой оболтус обижает малыша, и рабочий преподаст мальчику ненавязчивый урок мужества (М. Туровская. 7 с 1/2 и Фильмы Андрея Тарковского (1991)* В этом случае оба слова пишутся со строчной буквы и без кавычек.